# Application in foreground of victim computer

Tags: ios, security, penetration-testing

For a "hack it yourself"  workshop I am giving I would like to show the (not to technical) audience how easy it is to hack. I'm going to use a simple W7 VM with a vulnerable application to spawn a reverse shell on my Kali machine.

I then have full system privileges on the machine, but as these are not technical people I want to show some sparkle etc. So what I want to do is either:

1. Open browser navigate to a youtube "you got hacked!" video (this might be difficult)
2. Open a video that I already put on the machine
3. Open calc.exe in the foreground.

So my problem here is that I don't know how to open an application that shows in the foreground of the victim machine. So that it actually shows up on the screen!

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You could try to shell-execute a URL or simply start a new process. E.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "www.youtube.com"` will spawn a new firefox instance and automatically open the link `www.youtube.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly this does not work for me (trying with IE because I have an old machine).

Comment: Then again, even IE understands that shell argument. Try `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.youtube.com"`.

Comment: I have tried a bit more and what I find is that it opens in a different session (which makes sense). So the session of USER is very much different of the session of SYSTEM. Now I am trying to use runas in the shell so I can run it as the USER. But this requires the password of the user to be given. But the reverse shell I have doesn't allow me to insert it... (it just shows the text and then the normal C:/ etc..). I cannot pipe a password to runas or even put it on one line. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you're working with metasploit, it would be useful to keep 2 sessions open: One low-privileged session with user rights, and a seperate session in which privilege escalation to SYSTEM will be done. Then just execute the command in the session with user rights. You may also be able to use the `impersonate_token` module to impersonate another user on-the-fly. (https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/fun-incognito/)

Comment: Ok thanks! I"ll have to try that tomorrow. For now I have found psexec to work as well (just need to donwload it but with system rights that is no problem ;D). I'll try tomorrow and put you on amswer if it works! And I wasn't using metasploit but for a workshop that is just as nice indeed!

Comment: It indeed works with steal_token (in my version) but it is pretty weird and buggy to do. But hey! for workshop purposes perfect thanks! (Now how do I set your answer as the correct one with some minor adjustments?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer the question (just for clarity instead in the comments).
Thanks to Maximilian Gerhardt who gave the answer (I will set you as best answer if you want but I can't just from the comments!).

There are two ways that are good for this:

1. Download psexec.exe onto the "victim" pc and use that with psexec.exe -s -d -i [here the session token "1" works for me] calc.exe
2. If using a meterpreter shell you can use incognito mode  (offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/fun-incognito). And then use the impersonate_token method. This works great, but I cannot go back to being SYSTEM (getsystem doesn't work as there are no privilege escalation vulnerabilities present). So I have to exit and reuse the exploit. But for the workshop this works beautifully!

For those interested I use SLMail 5.5 on a W7 machine to show how easy "hacking" can be and what a hacker then can do with a computer. This for an awareness workshop, which is bigger then just this "show and tell" part.

steps:

1. nmap scan on port 110 with version detection to see "hey what is this? SLMail?"
2. google SLMail to find "Oh noes a buffer overflow, hmmmmm let's look into that!"
3. this is metasploit a tool hackers can use to exploit know systems (I have the manually made exploit with more explanation for interested people after the workshop with buffer overflow explained)
4. search in metasploit for SLMail, we find it and say use
5. "it works how cool! What can we do with it?" show webcam capture! (that is scary stuff :D).
6. Go to shell and show with whoami for the tech people that we are indeed system. then go to incognito mode and steal the token from the user that we see on the screen.
7. open up youtube with "hackerman" video (well had to choose one :D)
8. explain a bit that it is that easy for a script kiddy to get in if you don't update etc. etc. etc.
9. let awareness kick in and next time they do something dumb they might think: "o wait let's not do that!"

Cheers!